# Python-MIP InterfacingError('Gurobi environment could not be loaded, check your license.')

Tags: python, gurobi, integer-programming

I want to use Gurobi with python-mip. I run the following:

```
from mip import Model, GUROBI
Model("test_problem", solver_name=GUROBI)
```

I receive the following error: `InterfacingError('Gurobi environment could not be loaded, check your license.')`.

I followed [Python-MIP's instructions](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) to enable the use of Gurobi. I run `gurobi.sh` from my terminal and get the following output:

```
Gurobi Interactive Shell (mac64), Version 10.0.2
Copyright (c) 2023, Gurobi Optimization, LLC
Type "help()" for help

gurobi>
```

According to Gurobi's documentation, this means Gurobi has installed correctly (I left off my license details, but yes I have an active license). I call `echo $GUROBI_HOME` just to make sure I have the path required in Python-MIP's documentation set, and I get the output `/Library/gurobi1002/macos_universal2`, so I assume I do.

With all of this in mind, I was expecting my two lines of Python above to run without issue and instantiate a Model object.

Comment: How did you install gurobipy and your license?

Comment: Hi Greg! Thank you for the quick follow up. I'm trying out a single use WLS license right now for a column generation implementation, and it looks like Gurobi doesn't like that both my master and pricing problem are calling your solver (even though they don't do so in parallel). If for example I solve the master with CBC, the issue goes away.

Comment: To answer your question though, I just followed the [quickstart guide](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/quickstart.html) to install Gurobi on my Mac M1 and then I downloaded my license and placed it in ~/gurobi.lic. Running `gurobi.sh` didn't create any issues, so I think I'm just using my license in a way it wasn't intended. I'll talk with sales and get a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spoke with Gurobi support and it appears I just misunderstood how their licenses work. I had a single use license, which I understood to be applicable for solving `gurobi.Model` instances in series. If what I learned is correct, it turns out a single use license is a bit more restrictive, where multiple models are not allowed to be in memory at the same time, even if they're never solved in parallel. I upgraded to an unlimited use license to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Python-MIP does not find your Gurobi license like gurobipy does. Your academic WLS license allows for this use case. In general, you would only need a single license token to start the environment. In that single environment, you can create both main and pricing problems.